# Moving disk over a underlying image

Tags: graphics, image-processing, image, animation

I want to make the following animation. The basis is a image, for example Lena's photo. I will place a new layer over this image. This layer has a color, for example black. In this layer there is a recess in the shape of a circle. Through this circle you can see the photo of Lena. I want to move the circle with the visible bottom layer, creating an animation of a part of Lena's head. During this animation, several circles can slide across the screen.

[image]

I myself have tried several functions without the desired effect. Does anyone have a suggestion how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution is to use [`HighlightImage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightImage.html) which also has interactive example in the documentation that might be useful to you.

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Peppers"}];
HighlightImage[img, {Transparent, Disk[{170, 350}, 150], 
  Disk[{430, 300}, 75], Disk[{400, 60}, 50]}, {"Remove", Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just in case it isn't clear from Domen's posting, the full (interactive) answer is given in the linked documentation page.  ($+1$)